# PHP Call to a Postgres void function

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.0

Is there a best practice for issuing a parameterized command call (ExecuteNonQuery) to a postgres function using PHP?

Comment: Are you using PL/PHP from Command Prompt? Did you read the documentation of functions and arguments? https://public.commandprompt.com/documents/5#Functions-and-Arguments If so, what questions weren't answered by the documentation?

Comment: I'm attempting to write class methods use pg_... data access library.

Comment: Well, Pg's `void` functions return a scalar null, so you can always call them with a regular `SELECT the_function()` and discard the result row. I take it you're looking for other approaches, pros / cons, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices:

Parameterize your query (i.e. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php or similar)

I actually think it is a bad practice to return void.  I think it is almost always better to return some useful info.  However there is nothing special about void-returning functions.  You just call them like any other functions.